# T-SQL Get Records for this year grouped by month

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of data which looks like this

```
ID        CreatedDate   
A123      2015-01-01  
B124      2016-01-02  
A125      2016-01-03  
A126      2016-01-04
```

What I would like to do is group by month (as text) for this year only. I have some up with the following query but it returns data from all years not just this one:

```
 Select Count(ID), DateName(month,createddate) from table
 Where (DatePart(year,createddate)=datepart(year,getdate())
 Group by DateName(month,createddate)
```

This returns

```
Count    CreatedDate
4        January
```

Instead of

```
Count    CreatedDate
3        January
```

Where have I gone wrong? I'm sure it's something to do with converting the date to month where it goes wrong

Comment: The issue is not reproducible, at least not on my end.

Comment: You query outputs exactly result you want (3 January) on sample data you've posted.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested your code:

```
;WITH [table] AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
('A123',      '2015-01-01'),
('B124',      '2016-01-02'),
('A125',      '2016-01-03'),
('A126',      '2016-01-04')
) as t(ID, CreatedDate)
)

SELECT  COUNT(ID), 
        DATENAME(month,CreatedDate) 
FROM [table]
WHERE DATEPART(year,CreatedDate)=DATEPART(year,getdate())
GROUP BY DATENAME(month,CreatedDate)
```

Output was

```
3   January
```

I removed `(` near `WHERE`

Comment: Looks like it is right, must have made a mistake in my initial figures from the table

Answer (score 0):

```
 select count(id) as Count,
 case when month(createddate)=1 THEN 'Januray' END as CreatedDate
 from [table]
 --where year(createddate)=2016 optional if you only want the 2016 count
 group by month(createddate),year(createdDate)
```